# How to get the association data safety in Ecto Model?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a model `User` which has one `Subscription`. Now I want to get the data in related subscription. A user may have no subscription.

This is my code:

```
user = Repo.get(User, 1) |> Repo.preload(:subscription)

hash = %{name: user.name, subscription_type: user.subscription.type}
```

So here when I try to get `subscription_type`, if the subscription is nil, I will get an error.

In Ruby I can use `try` method `user.subscription.try(:type)` or safe navigation operator `user.subscription&.type`. How about in Elixir?

One way I can think of is: `user.subscription && user.subscription.type`

But I feel it's redundant, any idea?

Comment: `Repo.get(User, 1).preload(:subscription)` is not a valid [tag:elixir] code in the first place.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Sorry, just type by hand, updated.

Answer (score 1):

We barely get to the nested elements of maps/structs with a dot notation in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir); I would say [opinionated] it’s counter-idiomatic. Instead we use two approaches:

#### [Access](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html)

If all the elements in the chain were `maps` (or have implemented the `Access` behaviour in general,) we could use [`get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#get_in/2)

```rb
foo = %{bar: %{baz: 42}}
get_in foo, [:bar, :baz] #⇒ 42
get_in foo, [:sna, :fu] #⇒ nil
```

#### Pattern matching

[ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) schemas, unfortunately, are structs and do not implement `Access`; for those we might use pattern matching

```rb
hash =
  User
  |> Repo.get(1)
  |> Repo.preload(:subscription)
  |> case do 
    %User{name: name, subscription: %Subscription{type: type}} ->
      %{name: name, subscription_type: type}
    %User{name: name} ->
      %{name: name}
  end
```

#### [`Access.key/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#key/2)

Also, one might use `Access.key/2` to seeply get to the values in nested structs.

```rb
user = User |> Repo.get(1) |> Repo.preload(:subscription)
type = get_in(user, [Access.key(:subscription), Access.key(:type))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite [big topic](https://elixirforum.com/t/elixir-version-of-a-safe-navigation-operator-navigating-nil-in-maps-structs/6023/21) about safe navigation.
The easiest solution and idiomatically right would be pattern matching.

```rb
user = Repo.get(User, 1) |> Repo.preload(:subscription)
subscription_type = case user do
                      %{subscription: %{type: type}} when is_binary(type) -> type
                      _ -> nil
                    end
hash = %{name: user.name, subscription_type: subscription_type}
```

Comment: It has been never stated `type` must be binary.

Comment: elixir string are represented as binaries. of course we can change to `is_atom`, but I'm sure that column type will be stored as string, that's why I added this check in example

Comment: I'm referencing on josevalim [answer](https://elixirforum.com/t/elixir-version-of-a-safe-navigation-operator-navigating-nil-in-maps-structs/6023/22), quite respectful source